# Docker + GNOME + tightvncserver + noVNC

Tags: ubuntu, docker, gnome, vnc

I want to build a Docker image that installs Ubuntu GNOME Desktop, tightvncserver and noVNC to remote access the container from a web browser.

In my Dockerfile, I install all the necessary GNOME packages:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \

  ubuntu-desktop \
  gnome-panel \
  gnome-settings-daemon \
  metacity \
  nautilus \
  gnome-terminal \
```

My xstartup file is:

```
#!/bin/sh

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
/etc/X11/Xsession
vncconfig -iconic &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```

Unfortunately, when I login noVNC, I can only see a Desktop background and a single window; I have no menu bar, launchers etc.

I searched a long time around this topic but didn't find any clear answer how to make it work properly. Maybe I missed something out there. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly configure xstartup file for TightVNC with Ubuntu VPS GNOME environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296329/how-to-properly-configure-xstartup-file-for-tightvnc-with-ubuntu-vps-gnome-envir)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [something like this?](http://github.com/johnsonyue/oslab).
Client I used is the chrome's vncviewer

PS: It works fine except for some dbus errors at the build stage, wait for the timeout and the images should be built anyway.